# AngularJs defining global variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best way to define a global varible in `AngularJS`?

I know there are plenty of solutions about this topic, the most commom:

- Use a service;
- Use $rootScope;

I want an answer for a different context. For example:

- A commom url used for multiple requests in multiple services: `my/folder/class.php`;
- The name of a main module: `myApp`;
- A commom alert message for an error: `Failed to connect to the server, try again.`

Things that will be used all over the app, in different situations and will never change.

---

Looking around the internet I saw 2 other possibilities other then `$rootScope` and `services`:

- Use AngularJS `constants`;
- Use `JS` `var` outside of the main `ng` module;

So my question is: For the AngularJs scenario, what is the best alternative?

Do we really use `constants` for this situation? Is there any other provider for this purpose. Also I'd like to know whats the performance impact of the, if any.

Comment: Unless those values are supposed to change then I believe `constants` is the preferred way to go.

Comment: @SeanLarkin do you mean, by comparing `constant` vs `service`?

Comment: I removed my answer as I misunderstood the question. Both have to be injected to use. I suppose you could also use `value` as an option. Benefit for using `.constant` is that it can be injected into configuration and cannot be overridden by decorators.

Answer (score 0):

For true constants use Angular constants. If your values may need to be configured or calculated use an Angular service and expose getter functions. For strings you may want to consider localization, so use one of the Angular localization libraries to store these (I use Angular-localize).

Hope this is helpful.